# `npm install` doesn't install anything?

Tags: node.js

```
➜  eslinta git:(master) ✗ npm install eslint --save-dev
   eslinta@1.0.0 /Users/next/es6/jsmodules/eslinta
   └─┬ eslint@3.15.0
   ├─┬ babel-code-frame@6.22.0
   │ └── js-tokens@3.0.1
   ├─┬ chalk@1.1.3
   │ ├── ansi-styles@2.2.1
    ...

  npm WARN eslinta@1.0.0 No description
  npm WARN eslinta@1.0.0 No repository field.
  ➜  eslinta git:(master) ✗ eslint -v
  zsh: command not found: eslint
  ➜  eslinta git:(master) ✗
```

What's the reason of this problem?
I installed node by nvm.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time out to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). You need to add more details to your post, and more specifically, ask a clear and concise question.

Answer (score 0):

Command line modules are installed in a project at `./node_modules/.bin` so you can run eslint directly with `./node_modules/.bin/eslint`.  The better approach is to create a script entry in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "lint": "eslint"
}
```

because running commands from the `scripts` entry in `package.json` will automatically add `./node_modules/.bin` to the path.  This way you can run your lint with `npm run lint`

Comment: 1. And where's the Global Modules installed? 2. if I install locally `airbnb-eslint`, what should I do with `package.json`

Comment: Global packages are installed not in the project and somewhere different depending on the is and platform.  See https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb for getting started with configuring airbnb eslint rules, which are very good and I highly recommend

Answer (score -1):

Did you try installing eslint globally?

`npm install -G eslint eslinta@1.0.0`

Comment: yes, it works. Do you know why it doesn't work above?

Comment: -g will install eslint globally, but it's usually better to keep it installed on a per-project basis

Comment: @CaptEmulation And what would be the solution to keep per project installed packages bins available on PATH?

EDIT: Maybe add `./node_modules/.bin` to the PATH?

Comment: @marano no I would add my `eslint` scripts to my `package.json` `scripts` field because scripts run from there automatically have `./node_modules/.bin` on the PATH.  I can then run `npm run eslint` (or whatever script name you choose) to execute the command.